# How to create fire with mantaflow, I can only generate smoke not fire

Tags: fire

Could somebody please explain the new mantaflow fire simulation setting. I was unable to generate fire both in Cycles and Eevee. I play with all the setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is set the *Type* of the *Flow Object* to 'Fire' or 'Smoke and Fire' which basically adds a new volume (field) to the simulation (in addition to the temperature) for calculating the flames:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works